# How to show Google map in iOS8 with current location all annotation pin

Tags: iphone, ios8, mapkit

I have to show Google map in iOS8.0. I am able to open Google map **but map is not coming clearly. please check the screenshot**. I have given the permission in info.plist and also written corresponding code... please check below...

```
self.mLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.mLocationManager.delegate = self;
self.mLocationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.mLocationManager.distanceFilter = kDistanceFiveHundredMeters;

if ([self.mLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.mLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
if ([self.mLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.mLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
            [self.mLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

**And also I want show current location and all annotation which is showing on map together on map rect. How will I do it?**
[image]

Info.plist

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription  Location is required to find out where you    are

 NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription Location is required to find out where you are
```

Comment: Have you added key in AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Added in info.plist file.. not in app delegate.. please check the new line in above post.

Comment: How have you added the map ? From the xib or from your code ?

Comment: self.mMapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (NAVIGATION_SLIDER_GAP), mainScreen.bounds.size.width, mainScreen.bounds.size.height - (NAVIGATION_SLIDER_GAP))];
    self.mMapView.delegate = self; Already added the code..

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar: That's not a "Google map", `MKMapView` is an "Apple MapKit map".  The question has nothing to do with Google Maps.  Change the "google-maps" tag to "mkmapview".

Comment: Edited with MapKit tags..